# Using bst files with TinyTex

Tags: bibtex, tinytex

I am using TinyTex in Ubuntu. I like the "small and simple" philosophy of TinyTex, and it works really well with R and RStudio using RMarkdown.

But I have some documents I'd like to work with in the traditional LaTeX fashion. There was some pain in installing missing LaTeX packages, but I think I have all of the ones I need. My paper compiles and displays in TexWorks.

The problem I have is installing custom BST files for natbib. I can't for the life of me figure out where to put them so that TinyTex can see them. I've tried the same directory as the document, ~/.TinyTex/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst, ~/.TinyTex/texmf-local/bibtex/bst.

No matter where I put it, I get the following error when I try to compile with BibTex:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2020/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: ....
I couldn't open style file apsr.bst
---line 86 of file ...
 : \bibstyle{apsr
 :               }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file ...
(There were 2 error messages)
```

What can I do?

Comment: Isn't TinyTeX just a cut down TeX Live? Did you try `~/texmf/bibtex/bst/`?

Comment: @JosephWright yes but there's no such directory. just the two I mentioned -- /texmf-local and /texmf-dist

Comment: Where are the other bst files located? Presumably you can put your custom style in that folder. `kpsewhich plain.bst` in the terminal should give you the location.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to go, but I don't have kpsewich! Ubuntu tells me I need to install texlive binaries ... what I wanted to avoid the whole time :)

Comment: In that case just `sudo find . -name "plain.bst"` from root (`cd /`, *not* `cd ~`).

Comment: or even `-name "*.bst"` to get a complete overview of all the BST files on your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yihui Xie (author of TinyTex) solved this problem [here](https://github.com/yihui/tinytex/issues/319).

The issue is that I installed TinyTex first, and then I installed my LaTeX editor. When I did that, it automatically installed texlive for me, despite the fact that I had TinyTex installed already. So that when I was putting in these bst files into the TinyTex local directories, it was never seeing them!

The solution was to install my LaTeX editor with the --no-install-recommends option (on Ubuntu with apt) so that it didn't bring along texlive.